# Horizontal navigation menu in Bootstrap 3.0 - How can I add a Prev-Next arrow on top of it if I have lot of main menu?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) 3.0 and implemented the navigation menu. My media query break point for Desktop to Mobile view is at 800 pixels. So basically on a screen with 800 pixels and plus I want to show the desktop view. On a wider screen like a desktop I am able to show all 12 or so main menus in a single line. But if I go to an iPad then I get for example only 980 pixels. Here in this smaller screen my menu comes in two lines. I can't reduce my main menu count.

How I can make a previous - next arrow on top of the Bootstrap navigation so that the menu will always come in a single line, and I can traverse through all available menu in desktop mode?

[image]

I need to implement something like this.

I created a simple jsFiddle of the Bootstrap navigation having 12 main menus. Please expand the Result section wide enough to show the nav in desktop mode like follows:

Fiddle link: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vijayP/k63t7tqo/)
    `fiddle image`

http://jsfiddle.net/vijayP/k63t7tqo

[image]

Comment: Can you create a **DEMO**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```js
$('.direction-right').click(function() {
    var margin = $('.navbar-nav').css('margin-top');
    console.log(margin);
    console.log('-' + ($('.navbar-nav').height() - 50) + 'px');
    $('.navbar-nav').css('margin-top', margin == '-' + ($('.navbar-nav').height() - 50) + 'px' ? margin : '-=50px');
});

$('.direction-left').click(function() {
    var margin = $('.navbar-nav').css('margin-top');
    $('.navbar-nav').css('margin-top', margin == '0px' ? '0px' : '+=50px');
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $('.navbar-nav').css('margin-top', 0);  
    }
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .direction-right, .direction-left {
        display: none;
    }    
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        height: 51px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: calc(100% - 52px);
    }
    
    .direction-right, .direction-left {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
          
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">     
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
          
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <a href="#" class="direction-left pull-left navbar-brand"><</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="1.html">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="2.html">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="3.html">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="4.html">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="5.html">Menu 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="6.html">Menu 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="7.html">Menu 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="8.html">Menu 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="9.html">Menu 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="10.html">Menu 10</a></li>
            <li><a href="11.html">Menu 11</a></li>
            <li><a href="12.html">Menu 12</a></li>
          </ul>
            <a href="#" class="direction-right pull-left navbar-brand">></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k63t7tqo/3/

Or Try this one with a slider effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/k63t7tqo/7/

Comment: Thanks mimo for your help, but i don't think by this way i will be able to add sliding animation. Otherwise this is really good.

Comment: it's difficult to add a slider because you don't know how long your navigation will be. Possible solution: when you hit the right button you get the width of the left li element and substitutes it from the left margin of the ul element. Use overflow hidden so it will be out of the visible part. You can use jquery animate for the slider effect ;)

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to do this is you can use **jQuery plugins**
Like:

[jQuery Slider Tabs](http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/)

[SlideTabs](http://www.slidetabs.com/)

and many more.

A demo can be seen here.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/styles/jquery.sliderTabs.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/jquery.sliderTabs.min.js"></script>

<div id="mySliderTabs">
  <!-- Unordered list representing the tabs -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Menu 12</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just useful for tabs, but not if you have links to other pages in the navbar

Comment: Well you can just put your page url instead using #. Its common sense.