# How would one go about making a carousel style navbar for many tabs in Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've looked everywhere and I can't figure this out. I'm trying to have my navbar at the top of the page show five tabs, then for more, have a ">>" to the right and allow it to scroll the navbar to show more tabs. Is it even possible to do that with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible. Please have a look at below SO question:

[Horizontal navigation menu in Bootstrap 3.0 - How can I add a Prev-Next arrow on top of it if I have lot of main menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982428/horizontal-navigation-menu-in-bootstrap-3-0-how-can-i-add-a-prev-next-arrow-on)

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why I got downvoted...tough crowd I guess.

Comment: For some reason, when I use that code you linked, the arrows cause the navbar to scroll up the page by itself, even overlapping other content. Any thoughts?

Comment: must be an `overflow` issue. make sure that you set `overflow:hidden` for the navbar container so that it doesn't overlap other contents appearing below it. Hope you will tweak that CSS issue. Thanks...!

Comment: I do have overflow:hidden there already. Any idea what else it could be?